# How to reverse priority of spans in a SpannableString

Tags: android, html

The priority of spans that added to a spannable affects on appearance of it in a TextView.
When we add two nested Character Style to a spannable like below

```
SpannableStringBuilder sp = new SpannableStringBuilder();
String blue = "blue";
String red = "red";
sp.append(blue);
sp.append(red);
sp.append(blue);
sp.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), blue, 2*blue, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);        
sp.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, sp.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view)).setText(sp);
```

The order of adding character styles is important on appearance of text.
Android make a way to handle the priority of spans through Spanned.SPAN_PRIORITY flag. But when we use of Html.fromHtml(), priorities are not in our hands. So can i change span priorities of output of Html.fromHtmel or can i make new spannable from that and make new span priorities;

Answer (score 2):

I did for myself a little workaround. It creates new Spannable with spans reversed.

```
final Spannable revertSpans(Spanned stext) {
    Object[] spans = stext.getSpans(0, stext.length(), Object.class);
    Spannable ret = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(stext.toString());
    if (spans != null && spans.length > 0) {
        for(int i = spans.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            ret.setSpan(spans[i], stext.getSpanStart(spans[i]), stext.getSpanEnd(spans[i]), stext.getSpanFlags(spans[i]));
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Usage:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)finViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
Spanned stext = Html.fromHtml(text, null, myTagHandler);
Spannable sreverted = revertSpans(stext); 
tv.setText(sreverted);
```

Maybe this be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly specify the span priorities for `Html.fromHtml()`. Instead, you can take the `Spanned` returned from `Html.fromHtml()` and call `Spanned.getSpans()` to get the span objects. You can copy the spans to a new `Spannable`, such as a `SpannableStringBuilder`, using the `Spannable.setSpan()` method.

Here's a demo of how to use `Spanned.SPAN_PRIORITY_SHIFT` to get one span to apply before or after others.

```java
TextView textView;
SpannableStringBuilder ssb;
final ForegroundColorSpan BLUE = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);
final ForegroundColorSpan RED = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);

// 1: baseline
// all RED
textView = findViewById(R.id.text1);
ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello world!");
ssb.setSpan(BLUE, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ssb.setSpan(RED, 0, 12, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ssb);

// 2: reverse the setSpan() call order; not always convenient
// BLUE and RED
textView = findViewById(R.id.text2);
ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello world!");
ssb.setSpan(RED, 0, 12, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ssb.setSpan(BLUE, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ssb);

// 3: give BLUE higher priority; BLUE applies first and RED overrides it
// all RED
textView = findViewById(R.id.text3);
ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello world!");
ssb.setSpan(BLUE, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE | (0x01 << Spanned.SPAN_PRIORITY_SHIFT));
ssb.setSpan(RED, 0, 12, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE | (0x00 << Spanned.SPAN_PRIORITY_SHIFT));
textView.setText(ssb);

// 4: give RED higher priority; RED applies first and BLUE overrides it
// BLUE and RED
textView = findViewById(R.id.text4);
ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello world!");
ssb.setSpan(BLUE, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE | (0x00 << Spanned.SPAN_PRIORITY_SHIFT));
ssb.setSpan(RED, 0, 12, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE | (0x01 << Spanned.SPAN_PRIORITY_SHIFT));
textView.setText(ssb);
```

[image: Span priority demo]