# comparing two spanned strings in edittext in android

Tags: android, spannablestring, spanned

I am having a strange problem in my app. I have an edittext where I am getting some user input text. I am also enabling user to add formatting (Bold/italic etc) as well to the entered string. I then store that string into a json string. Further on in my flow in my app, I then display that same json string back into edittext. I then compare the displayed string in edittext to the one originally stored in the json string. Here is how the two strings differ

String 1: `<p dir="ltr"><i><b>Test</b></i></p>`

String 2:  `<p dir="ltr"><b><i>Test</i></b></p>`

As you can see above, the strings are slightly different as the sequence of tags are different. Even though they are actully the same string with same formatting.  Hence any comparision of these two strings fails, causing issues in my app.

Methods I use are
For String 1:

> testJson.put("my text", Html.toHtml(trimSpannable(new
>   SpannableStringBuilder(myEditText.getText()));

Then I use the below code to display that json back to edittext

> myOtherEditText.setText(trimSpannable((SpannableStringBuilder)(Html.fromHtml(testJson.getString("my
>   text"))));

For String 2:

> String2 = Html.toHtml(new SpannableString(myEditText.getText()));

Any suggestions anyone has here to help. Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to convert the `Spanned` into HTML?

Comment: updated my questions with the code examples

Comment: Do you actually need to compare the formatting? If not, call `toString()` to get plain text and compare that.

Comment: I need to compare the formatting, simple toString() compare will not help. For example if user has underlined some text then it need to match the exact span of that underline. In fact any other way of comparing two formatted strings will be very helpful.

Comment: This helped
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000088/how-to-reverse-priority-of-spans-in-a-spannablestring